# Logitech T650 touch click and right click do not work

Tags: windows-7, drivers, logitech-touchpad

I have a Logitech T650 wireless touch pad. I am using Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit. I charged the device, attached the USB receiver and let the drivers install.

Moving the cursor works, and some gestures (such as two finger scroll) work. However, tap to click and right click do not work, and the mouse cannot be clicked using the device.

I have searched around through forums and found a number of users experiencing this problem (in Windows 8 as well) with no useful help received from Logitech support.

The hardware does not seem to be faulty; cursor movements work (and in fact, work really well). I suspect it is a driver issue of some sort. What could be the problem and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that this device requires Logitech's SetPoint software to function correctly, but if you just follow the instructions and attach the device, the drivers that Windows installs automatically are not sufficient.

If you haven't plugged in the device and installed the default drivers yet, skip the next bit and go straight to installing SetPoint.

If you have already plugged the device in you should first **uninstall the existing drivers**. To do this, with the device plugged in:

1. Go to *Start* -> *Control Panel* -> *Device Manager*. Under "Mice and other pointing devices" look for "HID-compliant mouse". If you have more than one, detach other mice from your system to narrow it down or view the properties of each, click *Details*, select "Hardware Ids", and find the one that contains "VID_*046D*&PID_*C52B*" - that's the one.
2. Right click on the device in the device manager list and choose *Uninstall*.
3. Detach the device from your system and power off the touchpad.

I'm not sure if you actually need to uninstall the existing drivers first but I am a firm believer in starting from scratch with these types of things (if anybody has direct experience with this working please post in the comments).

Now **install SetPoint**:

1. Visit the [SetPoint download page](https://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/3131#download) (if the link is broken by the time you read this just search Logitech's site for "SetPoint").
2. Choose "Windows 7" or whatever, and download it. It is an inappropriately large 78MB (that's right, in 2014 your mouse drivers fit neatly onto only 217 double-density 5.25" floppies).
3. Run the installer.
4. Attach the T650's receiver and charge cable, and power on the touchpad. Give it a few seconds to install the drivers, then... tada! (You should now see "Logitech HID-compliant Unifying Mouse" in the device manager). Tap to click, tap lower right corner to right-click, tap then hold to drag.

The procedure should be similar with Windows 8. With Windows 10, if the above does not work, check out [Longmont Help's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1012724/245945) for other things to try.

You can configure the device through the SetPoint software. You can even check the battery status on the device. Cool!

Comment: Thanks! This worked, but I also had to install the firmware update in order to make it work, which can be downloaded at the same page you linked to

Answer (score 2):

My Logitech T650 seemed fine with Windows 7, then after I upgraded to Windows 10 it couldn't click anything anymore, similar to the problem posted above.
  I started roughly following the instructions in the solution above, found none of 3 Logitech devices sharing my unifying receiver, kb and touchpad combo, wireless mouse, and t650 touchpad, seemed to be effected at all by uninstalling Setpoint, which I did because the version offered at the Logitech site wouldn't install due to a newer version already running on my computer.
  I didn't reinstall Setpoint as it seems unnecessary.
  I have the Logitech Unifying software, which controls what connects to the unifying receiver. I originally had to install that sw to get the T650 recognized and working with Windows 7 before the upgrade.

I found a new version of firmware for the T650, version 041.001.00038, on the Logitech site which it claims adds the clicking and double-clicking functionality for the t650.
  I downloaded that executable, then ran it, nothing seemed to happen and the t650 was still not clicking.

I found out that the Unifying software offers "Update Firmware" in advanced settings, I used that, it updated and the t650 works properly now, and I don't have Setpoint installed anymore, at least it is not listed in All Apps nor in the list of Apps to uninstall in Control Panel's Apps and Features.